# System.OutOfMemoryException при добавлении элемента в словарь

Tags: c#, память, outofmemoryerror

Возникла проблема с ограничениями памяти для приложения. Из того что я понял: для приложения или под созданный объект (в моем случае это словарь) выделяется не больше 2Гб памяти. Хотелось бы создать словарь, который мог бы быть размера как минимум свободной части оперативной памяти. Как это сделать?

StackTrace исключения:

```
 в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Resize(Int32 newSize, Boolean forceNewHashCodes)
 в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
 в System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
```

Comment: *"который мог бы быть размера минимум размера оперативной памяти"* -- он таким быть не может.

Comment: Хорошо, а каким может быть ?

Comment: Он может быть размером максимум с объем *свободной* оперативной памяти. Но нужен *непрерывный* объем, что маловероятно. Рассчитать на основе имеющейся общей и свободной оперативной памяти сколько может занять один объект -- ненужная задача. Вы чего добиться-то хотите?

Comment: размером с оперативную память не может быть - нужно где то ведь и саму программу разместить, и операционную систему.

Если у Вас 32битное приложение, то в стандартной ситуации больше 2 гигов никак не получить (можно спецключик операционной системе дать - тогда максимум 3).

Comment: Для этого и придумали СУБД. Храните словарь в базе.

Comment: Есть данные, которые я считываю из файлов. Объект типа {A, B}. Хочу проверить для каждого А сколько B.

Comment: Размер оперативной памяти это было сказано условно, понятно что свободная память..

Comment: в идеале, не нужно все загружать в память.Можно читать и обновлять данные "на лету". Для более детального алгоритма нужно более детальное описание задачи (и лучше это сделать отдельным вопросом).

Comment: Не хочется заморачиваться с базой данных, потому что мне нужно один раз пройтись по данным, посмотреть на результат и забыть.

Comment: Если вам 100% нужен словарь - может вам нужно рассмотреть вариант "древесного" словаря, хранить не слова а буквы на каждом уровне - тогда обьём может уменьшится. И поиск в дереве будет менее ресурсоёмким

Comment: Ну и вы должны понимать, что в системах с пейджингом и виртуальной памятью (например, Windows) вашим ограничителем является не размер оперативки (RAM), а виртуального адресного пространства (плюс файла подкачки, да).

Comment: @andreycha а зачем для .net словаря нужен именно "непрерывный" кусок памяти?

Comment: @alexolut словарь работает на массивах. А массив -- это цельный объект, для которого нужен непрерывный кусок памяти.

Comment: @andreycha т.е. косвенной адресации там нет и сразу имеем ячейки с данными, а не со ссылками на данные?

Comment: @alexolut ячейки, конечно же, хранят ссылки на ключ и значение (либо включают их, если ключ/значение не являются ссылочными типами). Но там, во-первых, два массива -- один массив интов (4 байта), а второй массив [записей](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/6d8e35702d74cf71.html) (8 байт + ключ и значение, либо ссылки на них). При определенном сочетании "количество пар/наличие свободного блока" можно получить OOM.

Comment: @andreycha ну т.е. получается непрерывный кусок нужен если ключ+значение типы значения. А если они ссылочные, то уже могут храниться в совершенно другой области памяти.

Comment: @alexolut да. Если обобщить, то непрерывный кусок в памяти нужен в любом случае. Его объем и будут ли там храниться сами ключи-значения зависят от того, ссылочные они или нет.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сперва об `OutOfMemoryException`. Вопреки расхожему мнению, это исключение не означает, что закончилась память. Оно означает, что отсутствует требуемый *непрерывный* объем памяти. При этом свободной памяти еще может быть много, просто она фрагментирована. Например, CLR хочет выделить участок в 100 Мб, но есть только 20 свободных участков по 50 Мб. Свободная память есть, при этом `OutOfMemoryException` тоже есть.

Со словарем проблема заключается в том, что для изменении его размера требуется, грубо говоря, в два раза больше памяти, чем он занимает. Т.е. если на данный момент ваш словарь полностью заполнен и занимает 100 Мб (сам объект словаря, ключи/значения при этом могут храниться отдельно), то при добавлении очередного элемента нужно увеличить размер словаря, и на это требуется выделить 200 Мб памяти.

Теперь про ограничения. 2 Гб -- это объем памяти, выделяемый для 32-битного приложения (2^32). Для того, чтобы получить возможность кушать больше памяти (2^64), приложение должно быть 64-битным. При этом необходимо также включить опцию [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), которая позволит иметь массивы объемом больше 2 Гб.

Также вам стоит посмотреть внимательнее на ваш алгоритм, возможно его можно пересмотреть в сторону уменьшения потребления памяти.

Резюмируя в порядке важности:

1. Пересмотрите алгоритм (можете выложить его здесь отдельным вопросом и вам постараются подсказать).
2. Сделайте приложение 64-битным и включить опцию `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`.

Comment: Для 64-битных приложений нужно ещё по идее [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054).

Comment: @VladD да, точно! Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно.

Comment: Получается, что про удвоенный размер надо говорить именно в контексте непрерывного размера *таблицы*. Т.к. если в исходные 100Мб входят ссылочные key/value, то их всё же не надо перемещать. А стало быть и памяти потребуется выделять не 200Мб, а меньше.

Comment: @alexolut я писал про сам словарь как объект. В этом случае фраза про удвоение справедлива. Думаете, стоит уточнить?

Comment: @andreycha возможно стоит добавить, что это именно под потроха (таблицу) словаря. С другой стороны, люди могут и комментарии почитать :)

Comment: @alexolut лучше обновлю :). Спасибо за замечание.